# 2sxc Gallery - The requested content can not be loaded. Please try again later

Tags: image, gallery, 2sxc, dnn9

DNN 09.09.01 / 2sxc 11. 22.1 / Image Gallery v5

App installation without problem, but when you click on image to show in Fancy box - you got message; The requested content can not be loaded. Please try again later.

I tested this with 2sic DNN Instant Bootstrap 4 theme and it is working just fine.

However, on this site I am using other DNN Theme ("Professional" Theme from DNNVista, Bootstrap 3, link; https://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-details/professional-15-colors-mega-menu-bootstrap-responsive-dnn-6x-7x-8x-dnn-9x) and this error occurred every time I click on a single photo.

I am aware that this Theme is full of bugs and I probably wasted 99$ for it, but would like to find out what is wrong and try to fix it in this particular Theme.
But - I don't know where to start, because there is no errors in Admin Log.

Any similar situations or ideas, please?

(sorry if I did not express my self clearly - English is not my Mother Tongue. Please ask if you need clarification)

UPDATE:
I found that, from some reason, hyperlinks for pictures are parsed without question mark after filename, but can't find a reason for such behaviour because everything is correct in app template.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess - probably you have some JS replacing other JS - like Fancybox being loaded 2x in different versions. Best check the Chrome-Network to verify.